# How use Rc Refcell in rust (and stdweb)

Tags: rust

i have a litle problem with this code:

I have two closure and I want the variable *counter* to be used in both of them.

```
fn main() {
    stdweb::initialize();


    let counter_div = document().query_selector(DIV_SELECTOR_NAME).unwrap().unwrap();
    // create Rc RefCell struct here 
    let mut counter = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ClickCounter::new()));

    counter_div.clone().add_event_listener(move |_: MouseDownEvent| {
        // ERROR move How make this work?
        counter.clone().borrow_mut().increment();
    });


    let upgrade_div = document().query_selector(UPGRADE_DIV_SELECTOR_NAME).unwrap().unwrap();
    upgrade_div.clone().add_event_listener( move |_: MouseDownEvent|{

       // ERROR move! 
       counter.clone().borrow_mut().upgrade_click(upgrade);
    });


    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Rc` with `move` closures, you need to clone *first*, and then move the variable into the closure. With the code you've written, you're first cloning the variable *after*  it has been moved into the closure, meaning that it is not available when the second closure tries to do the same.

An example:

```rust
let counter = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ClickCounter::new()));

{
    // Clone into a new variable outside of the closure.
    let cloned_counter = counter.clone();

    counter_div.add_event_listener(move |_: MouseDownEvent| {
        // Note: We're no longer cloning here.
        cloned_counter.borrow_mut().increment();
    });
}

// ...

{
    // Clone the counter variable on line 1 again.
    let cloned_counter = counter.clone();
    upgrade_div.add_event_listener(move |_: MouseDownEvent| {
        cloned_counter.borrow_mut().upgrade_click(upgrade);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I know there is no better solution?

Comment: It depends, what do you need for a better solution? This is typically how I solve this, and I've yet to see a better pattern to solve this problem, based on how closures work in Rust.